# Smart cropping tool?

Tags: photography

I have a bunch (1200) photos I need to crop. They're all of people sitting in a chair, facing the camera. Their heads are at varying angles and their hair size / heights differ (e.g. one might have their head tilted to the left, one to the right, one might be really short and one might have an afro and due to the camera being fixed, needs special consideration when cropping). They're generally standing in front of a plain board, but sometimes the board is visible on the edges of the photos

Is there a "smart crop" tool that will detect a face (or recognise a plain background) and either bulk crop or let me crop quicker than doing it manually?

EDIT: Specifically, I'm looking for something that will let me do a head / shoulders crop and preferably leave a gap above their head (so it looks aesthetically pleasing. These images will go on identification cards)

Comment: For which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I have all these varieties of software that crop multiple images in bulk mode. You can select from these which is a match for your requirements.

1. [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/)  : IrfanView is a software that crops multiple images of multiple types like **BMP, JPG, TIFF, PNG, PSD** and many more image formats. This software supports for **Windows NT, 2000, XP, 2003 , 2008, Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8**. The main advantage of this tool is to have a **print** option also.
2. **ImageMagick**  : ImageMagick is an open source image cropping tool and you can get pre-built binaries for **macOS, Windows, Unix** from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

   See: [Usage - ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Cutting and Bordering](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/).
3. **JPEGCrops**  : It is a *free tool to crop multiple JPEG images* in bulk and runs on Windows only. For more information about cropping, check out
   [how to crop your pictures for maximum impact](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-crop-images-and-make-your-photos-look-awesome-179523).
   To download **JPEGCrops free for Windows** see this [link](http://ekot.dk/programmer/JPEGCrops/).
4. [GIMP](https://francoismalan.com/2013/01/how-to-batch-separate-crop-multiple-scanned-photos/)  :  Its basic interface is just similar to **Photoshop** with functionality features, as it is an alternative to Photoshop. GIMP is easy to use and customizable software.

Comment: I'm currently using JPEGCrops which is great if the images are all similar and you can just pick "bulk crop all", but it has no **smart** crop for the scenario I'm describing. GIMP is the same. It has a variety of crops, and a few plugins / scripts to crop, but nothing that can detect a head / shoulders and center the crop around that. I just checked out IrfanView and it too has no "smart crop". I'll check out ImageMagick, but a cursory glance suggests it's missing a smart crop also